# Access Parent Class from member without storing pointer of Parent

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to safely access the parent class from a member without the need to store the pointer of the parent class in the member? Something like a this pointer but just a parent pointer?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>

template< class Member, class Parent, ptrdiff_t parentToMemberOffset>
struct ParentAccess
{
  Parent & parent() { return *reinterpret_cast<Parent*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(static_cast<Member*>(this)) - parentToMemberOffset); }
};

template<class Parent, ptrdiff_t parentToMemberOffset>
struct A : ParentAccess<A<Parent,parentToMemberOffset>, Parent, parentToMemberOffset>
{
  void notifyParent() { this->parent().notify(); }
};

struct Host
{
  uint64_t counter = 123;
  A<Host, 8 /*what safe here?*/> a;

  void notify() { counter++; std::cout << "counter is " << counter; }
};

int main()
{
    Host h;
    h.a.notifyParent();
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/Nps2Ye

Comment: The short answer is almost certainly "no". The `offsetof()` macro obtains the offset of a member within a type, but (1)  (IIRC) only works for complete types - in your example, it can't be used to find the offset of `a` within `Host`, as `Host` is incomplete at that point  (2)  before C++17, it only works for standard-layout types, from C++17 it is conditionally supported (3)  it cannot be implemented in standard C++ (i.e. requires "compiler magic"). Given all those limitations of `offsetof()` it is hard to envisage a way in standard C++ to implement something that meets your requirement

Comment: I suspected this. At the point the offset is needed, the alignment properties of A is also not decided (the offset number itself could have an impact on the alignment). Nevertheless such a feature (a parent pointer like a this point) would offer great possibilities to be not considered for a language extension....

Answer (score 0):

A solution is:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>

template< class Member, class Parent, size_t memberId  = 0>
struct ParentAccess
{
  const static ptrdiff_t offset;
  Parent & parent() { return *reinterpret_cast<Parent*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(static_cast<Member*>(this)) -
    offset ); }
};

template<class Parent, size_t memberId = 0>
struct A : ParentAccess<A<Parent, memberId>, Parent, memberId>
{
  void notifyParent() { this->parent().notify(); }
};

struct Host
{
  enum MemberId { A0, A1 };
  uint64_t counter = 123;
  A<Host/*,A0*/> a;
  A<Host,A1> a1;

  void notify() { counter++; std::cout << "counter is " << counter << std::endl; }
};

// define the offsets
template<>
const ptrdiff_t ParentAccess<A<Host>,Host>::offset = offsetof(Host, a);
//template<>
//const ptrdiff_t ParentAccess<A<Host,Host::A1>,Host,Host::A1>::offset = offsetof(Host, a1); 
// or using a macro to define the offset
#define DEFINE_PARENT_ACCESS_OFFSET(parentClassName, memberClass, memberName, memberId) \
template<>\
const ptrdiff_t ParentAccess<memberClass<parentClassName,parentClassName::memberId>,parentClassName,parentClassName::memberId>::offset = offsetof(parentClassName, memberName) 
DEFINE_PARENT_ACCESS_OFFSET(Host,A,a1,A1);

int main()
{
    Host h;
    h.a.notifyParent();
    h.a1.notifyParent();
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/JeZ2lh

Let's call it "Zero-Overhead Member to Class Instance Pointer Pattern".